# Junit for functions depending on other applications

Tags: java, maven, junit

I need to implement Junit for my application(written in java) that is developed using maven. Some of the functions in my application depend on others applications, where it gets the service of that application and use it in my application to connect to db etc when we launch it in the SDN controller along with other applications. how to test the functions that are dependent on other applications and connect to db?

Comment: by mocking those calls

Comment: @Stultuske make that an answer (plus an example :))

Comment: how do you mock the call? I tried adding dependency for those applications in my application

Comment: I've added a link in my answer to a tutorial

Answer (score 2):

If you need to call methods from other services (or even within the same library), you can mock these calls, and decide in the unit test itself, what the response is, so your unit test is focused purely on that unit.

There are different mocking libraries you can use, Mockito, or unitils.easyMock for instance:

```
@RunWith(StveJunit4TestClassRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

  @TestedObject
  private MyService service;

  @Mock
  @InjectIntiByType
  private ExternalService external;
  // this for all services used in your service

  @Test
  public void testMethod(){
    Person result = new Person("Jack", "American");
    EasyMock.expect(external.findPerson("Jack")).andReturn(result);
    EasyMockUnitils.replay();
    // this tells you, your tested service is going to call the external service
    // and passes "Jack" as param, with result as returned value

    String country = service.getPersonCountry("Jack"); // assume this returns the country 
//  of the person returned by the external service
    assertEquals(result.getCountry(), country);

  }
}
```

This is just an example, there are plenty more ways to do so.

EDIT: Here's a link to a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EasyMock/article.html) you can check out